# Con un botón, como pasar todos los elementos de tipo checkbox seleccionados a un '<div>'

Tags: php, php5

Con un botón, como pasar todos los elementos de tipo checkbox seleccionados (quiero mostrar su valor solo) en un formulario a un elemento HTML '' que esta situado en el mismo archivo php.
Este es el código que por ahora he desarrollado. Viene de otro archivo php.

Os dejo un enlace del código que meter todo aquí lleva mucho trabajo:
[Ver Código aquí](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13lxueTbbYVHK9XaMSclqS9BIqCtqHX66)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludo, puedes usar JS el evento Change() para que cuando el checkbox cambie de estado, este pueda pasarle el valor al elemento que deseas.
Ejemplo:

```
<p id="checkboxValue">
    //Aqui vamos a poner el valor de nuestro checkbox
</p>
<label for="check">Está este activo?</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check" value="Si" name="check">

<script type="text/javascript">
        //Se crea un evento para que detecte cada vez que se ejecute un cambio en el checkbox.
        $('#check').change(function(){
            //En la siguiente linea lo que hace es evaluar si esta checked e imprime según la condición
            $('#checkboxValue').text(($(this).is(':checked')) ? 'Si' : 'No');
        });
</script>
```

Ahora, si quieres pasar todos los valores de los elementos, seria mediante una clase que lo tengan todos los checkbox y con un $.each() recorrer cada elemento y anidar al div.
Ejemplo:

```
var texto ='';
    $.each('#checkbox', function(index,element){
        texto += ' '+$(this).val();
});
$('div').text(texto);
```

Espero haberte ayudado. :)

Comment: Esto la verdad es que si que funcionaría, pero por desgracia en mi caso no se me permite el uso de otro lenguaje de programación, solo PHP y el HTML5 para mostrar la página.

Comment: Entonces seria enviarlo por get. en vez de hacer un POST asi recoje los valores de cada uno de los checkbox y entonces recoje el get mostrandolo en el div. Me deja saber si me di a entender...

Comment: Me ayudaste con eso. ¡Muchas gracias compañero!.

Comment: Fue un gusto poder contribuir. :)